# Coordinate (ArrayList)

Tags: java, arraylist, coordinates

I'm having trouble formatting when using coordinates.

```
public class Coordinate {
  public int x;
  public int y;

  public Coordinate( int x, int y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }
}
```

So, later, when I'm trying to find the location of my rabbit, I use:

```
    Coordinate (x, y) = rabbit.get(i);
```

And that doesn't work, but this does:

```
    Coordinate z = rabbit.get(i);
```

I want to find the x and y values so I'm confused as to how to do that and why the Coordinate (x, y) doesn't work.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: You didn't tell us what language you are using, or post the get functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your attributes x,y of `Coordinate` are `public`:

```
Coordinate z = rabbit.get(i);
int xCor = z.x; //this is your x coordinate
int yCor = z.y; //this is your y coordinate
```

Normaly these attriubtes are `private` and you access them with a getter/setter-Method:

```
public class Coordinate {
  private int x;
  private int y;

  public Coordinate( int x, int y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }

  public int getX(){
    return this.x;
  }

  public void setX(int newX){
    this.x = newX;
  }
  //same for Y
}

//in the main program.
    Coordinate z = rabbit.get(i);
    int yourX = z.getX() //this is your x coordinate
    int yourY = z.getY() //this is your y coordinate
```

I assume you use Java, so I added the `Tag`, this enables highlighting. This works with other languages in the same way.